# Is it possible to get the query value in a SQL if it doesnt return result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine this db table:

```
|id |value|
|1a |a    |
|2b |b    |
|3c |c    |
```

And the following SQL:

```
select * from bar b where b.id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Is it possible to get something like the following:

```
|id |value   |
|1a |a       |
|2b |b       |
|3c |c       |
|4d |<null>  |
```

Basically, I wanna know which query param didn't return a value.

Comment: if you have a list of `id`s you want to query for, then yes it is, but not with that syntax.

Comment: @ShamSUP yeah, for sure that sql is dumb and wrong. i was wondering what the correct sql to accomplish this.

Comment: well it would depend where you are getting the IDs from

Comment: "hard coded", i have ~200 guids which i need to check against a table. and the guid is the table's primary key

Comment: Is it possible to put the guids you need to test for into a table of their own?

Comment: i dont see why not, i just copy the guid from some text file and formatted it so that itll work inside an "in clause"; either a table or a view

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an in-line values with all desired values. Then `LEFT JOIN` your table to this:

```
select t1.id, t2.* 
from (
   SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN bar AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: @YaoChen You have to build a look up table in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to insert your IDs into a database table of their own, you can use something like this

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM (SELECT id FROM guids) as t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```